# Custom File Format in AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation, capture, file-format

I am developing an osx capture app,
I can use File Format `UTIs` provided by `AVFoundation` to assign the file output format like `.mov`, `.mp4`, `.m4v` and etc.

Can I create custom File Format `UTIs` to save capture file such as `.mkv` or `.flv` ?

[Declaring New Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_declare/understand_utis_declare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319-CH204-SW1)
I found this link to declare new `UTIs`, but don't know how to integrate third-party `libraries` with this.

And does anybody know where can I find third-party `library` to save capture file in `.mkv` format ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can customize `AVCaptureFileOutput`, although you are free to add `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and `AVCaptureAudioDataOutput` outputs to your capture session and then create your files from the resulting video and audio `CMSampleBuffer`s using whatever containers and codecs you like.

For `.mkv` and `.flv` containers `libffmpeg` or `libav` come to mind. If, within the containers, you're thinking of using `h264` and `aac` encoders, I would use the iOS implementations as they're very efficient.

Comment: Very helpful hint. Thanks so much, I'll try the solution.